# How to highlight code block with material mkdocs package?

Tags: python, yaml, markdown, documentation, mkdocs

I am using material mkdocs package and I want to to highlight lines 7-31 of a JSON code block and I am not sure how to do it. I been have looked through the [documentation](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/code-blocks/#highlighting-specific-lines) and have tried many things for a while and nothing has solved my problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this simple problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution was very simple yet not documented anywhere

```
hl_lines="7-31"
```